# How do I batch create revisions of all posts?

Tags: posts, wpdb, revisions, post-status, wp-update-post

I cleaned up an old-site from pasted tags, manually created lists, etc, and I'd like to keep the old posts as "revisions", so we can easily "compare" with the old posts and retrieve/revert the original content if needed.

So I should either injecting the revision rows in the new DB or just naturally create them in the old WP installation, by batch-updating all the posts…

…or starting from the new cleaned-up dev installation and injecting the revisions.

The problem is the old site didn't even use revisions (version 1.6 or 2 or so), so before I even try anything, I should MAKE wordpress to generate the right revisions itself (so the injections just adds content in existing rows, not whole rows with missing references etc)

I know there are several places where the revisions and actual posts are linked/related/referenced so the process should be mostly done by wp functions and the fewer manual DB manipulations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to upgrade the old installation to a current wp version and reapply the changes. Unless it is a very big site you are probably going to waste more time in researching , coding and debugging an automatic solution then what it will take you to manually edit the posts.